# How to create automated or scheduled periodic task on firestore for a flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app that uses firebase firestore and I would like to do some autmoated or schduled periodic tasks to be done on firestore.

for instance:
in a collection, I have two fields, Result (String) and Date(timestamp).

I want when Date is less than Datetime.now, to automatically change the Result field value to be "0".

how can I achieve such autmoated function without the need to do initiate it from my side?

I though about a period task (let's say every two hours) to take snapshot from the collection where date is less than datetime.now, then to apply for loop to update the database for these document with Result = 0.

how can I do this periodic schedued task?

is there a more intellegent way to do this? somthing to be set on firestore to do he change autmotically?

Comment: Firestore triggers are triggered upon creation / update / deletion of a document. If this is not sufficient, you would need to offer more information why this is not working for in your case.

Comment: Hello, triggers is not suitble to my case, becaus I need to perform the function regardless an update happened to the collection or not. I need it to be done on periodic bases, so best is scheduled cloud functions as mentioned below. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to achieve this:

1. Set up a [firestore security rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields) that does this check whenever one document in your collection is updated.
2. Set up a [scheluded cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that does what you said in the question
3. Set up a cloud function that [is triggered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_for_all_changes_to_a_document) everytime a document in that collection is updated.

Comment: thanks remarcoble, I am new to flutter and firestore generally, I guess triggers won't be the best for my case because the collection may not have any change and I still need this check to be done and implemented. so best I guess schduled cloud function, wil go through this and check. thanks

Comment: I've checked the schduled function and hoesntly don't know how to adapt it to my case, should this be done by pub/sub? what should be the message of that?

Comment: @SherifSaidElahl Just write a function that looks something like this `exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 hours')
  .onRun((context) => {
  // Read snapshot from the collection where date is less than datetime.now, then apply for loop to update the database for these document with Result = 0.
});`

Comment: Thanks, I was missing how to link the pub/sub with a function on the cloud interface, will try this, thanks again